# Should JSON API entities include a relationship for its parent?

Tags: json-api, coding-style

I haven't been able to find a clear answer, hoping someone can help.

If we have, say, a blog with posts, and each post can have comments, and each comment a related user. Is it against convention, if I request the comment, to include both the user *and* the post in the relationships?

```
data: {
  type: 'comments',
  id: '1',
  relationships: {
    post: {...}, //should this be here?
    user: {...},
  }
  attributes: {...},
},
included: {...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **paulsm4** correctly stated: "it is up to you".

But I can give you some advice about that.

In such situations, you can give the caller of the API the choice of having such links or not via a querystring flag, like

`?relationships=post,user`

In this case, if you do not specify the relationship flag, you'll get the simple comment data or you can decide to give them all; in the second case, you can use *relationships* as a sort of filter.

In some APIs, I've seen also a more invasive approach: embed the related object directly in the returned JSON.

With the same technique as before:

`?embed=post,user`

This should produce an embedded JSON object in the current JSON reply including the original objects just as you were asking something like "GET /post/123" or "GET /user/456" separately. This can be handy in some situations.

Often this flag is named "expand" denoting same or similar behaviour.

For an example open [this API documentation from Atlassian](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.11.2/) and search for "expand".

It does exist an old "standard" for your problem called [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) that speaks about linking and embedding in REST APIs.

Even the Wordpress API offers such features, give it a look in the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/linking-and-embedding/).

An alternative to this is to rewrite the entire API in [GraphQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL) leveraging the REST approach.

Comment: The answer is not related to JSON API specification. In JSON API specification you have `include` query param to ask the server to include some related records. The response is than called a [Compound Document](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents). There is no reason to hide relationships from API consumer especially not as the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Should JSON API entities include a relationship for its parent?

A: I assume that's entirely up to you!

If your JSON is defined by some third party, then you have to live with what they gave you.  Please post details on how the JSON is specified.

Otherwise, if you're "inventing" the format yourself:

1. One possibility is to have a `relationships:` field with a link to the "parent".
2. Perhaps a better solution might to invent a "container" (perhaps a simple array!) to hold your "records".
3. If this were a database, I'd have a "posts" table, and a "comments" table.  The "comments" table would have a "Post ID" column as a foreign key into the "posts" table.

'Hope that helps ... at least a bit...

Comment: The format is specified by [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/) as said in the question.

Answer (score -1):

JSON API specification does not make any requirements on the *attributes* and *relationships* being included in a *resource object*. The specification is just saying how they must be formatted if they are included. If I did not missed anything, specification does not even require that all *resource objects* of the same type must have same *attributes* and *relationships*.

But I would argue that there isn't any value in not including the relationships. JSON API specification does not require a [*relationship object*](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) to include [*resource linkage*](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) data. On the contrary it's only talking about resource linkage data in context of a [*compound document*](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents), in which it's used "to link together all of the included resource objects without having to GET any URLs via links."

It's totally valid and could be considered best practice to only provide [*related resource link*](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links) if the related resources are not included in the payload. Constructing such a link would not put any workload on your server since it does not require to query the database. It also does not make any relevant difference in payload size.

An example of a payload using both techniques would look like this. It assumes that the request explicitly asked to include related user using [`include` query param](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes).

```
// GET https://examples.com/api/v1/comments/1?include=user

{
  data: {
    type: 'comments',
    id: '1',
    relationships: {
      post: {
        links: {
          related: 'https://examples.com/api/v1/comments/1/post'
        }
      },
      user: {
        data: {
          type: 'users',
          id: '2'
        },
        links: {
          related: 'https://examples.com/api/v1/comments/1/user'
        }
      },
    }
  },
  included: [
    {
      type: 'users',
      id: '2',
      attributes: {
        name: 'John Doe'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You may also want to include a [*relationship link*](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships), which "allows the client to directly manipulate the relationship." [*Update relationships* chapter](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-relationships) of spec gives a deep dive into what you could accomplish using relationship links.